# React Native SafeAreaView horizontal-only

Tags: react-native, react-native-safe-area-view

Is it possible to use the react native SafeAreaView (`react-native-safe-area-context`) only horizontally (or remove the generated top padding)? When using it e.g. in a modal that slides from the bottom, the iPhone X spacing is added on the top although it's actually far away from the screen top. It should only add the necessary spacings to the left and right in landscape.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does using the [`edges`](https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context#edges) prop work for you?

```
<SafeAreaView edges={['left', 'right']} />
```

You can add `bottom` to the above array if you want it removed from the top only.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't find that prop... Thank you!